# Keywords extracted from text using KeyBERT and lambda function appear to be similar

Tags: python, function, nlp, keyword, bert-language-model

I am trying to extract keywords from text held in a pandas dataframe column.

The dataframe's name is `memo_` and the column's name is `Text`. I am applying the KeyBERT model as shown below. I am not getting the right output. The keywords seem to be similar for all rows despite the text being different. Any guidance on this will be helpful.

```py
kw_model = KeyBERT(model='all-mpnet-base-v2')
memo_['Text'].apply(lambda x: kw_model.extract_keywords(x ,keyphrase_ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words='english', highlight=False, top_n=10))
```

Comment: Please do not rollback these edits any more. Your post has been objectively improved, all users are encouraged to edit posts for clarity and grammar, while preserving the original meaning. Further rollbacks will result in your post being locked, which will have the unwanted side effect of blocking all further interaction on it.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a minimal working example below using the information you've provided. The output shows that the results are not similar for all rows. This suggests one (or both) of following things may be happening in your code:

1. Your dataframe's 'Text' column contains entries that are *very* similar (if not identical). Double check that they are actually unique entries.
2. When you increase the ngram range of the keywords to extract, the `KeyBERT` model tends to "latch onto" a particular high scoring keyword (ngram = 1), and then produces larger ngram results (ngram >= 2) that repeatedly contain that particular high scoring keyword. To illustrate this, see the output below when the ngram range is set to 1 vs. 3: you can see that "camouflague" appears in 6/10 of the results, and "hiding" appears in 4/10. If each text in your dataframe contains very similar (if not identical) top N keywords (when the ngram range = 1), then this may explain why you are seeing very similar results when the ngram range is set to 3.

I suggest checking for those two things and see if that explains why results are *too* similar. Also cross-check your full code with the example below and see if there are any deltas that may be causing erroneous results.

### KeyBERT Example

```py
import pandas as pd
from keybert import KeyBERT

# Create dummy text
data = {'Text': [
    "The spot was perfect for camouflage. At least that's what she thought when she picked the spot. \
    She couldn't imagine that anyone would ever be able to see her in these surroundings. \
    So there she sat, confident that she was hidden from the world and safe from danger. \
    Unfortunately, she had not anticipated that others may be looking upon her from other angles, \
    and now they were stealthily descending toward her hiding spot.",

    "They had always called it the green river. It made sense. The river was green.\
     The river likely had a different official name, but to everyone in town, \
     it was and had always been the green river. So it was with great surprise \
     that on this day the green river was a fluorescent pink."
]}


memo_ = pd.DataFrame(data)  # Create dataframe
kw_model = KeyBERT(model="all-mpnet-base-v2")  # Instantiate KeyBERT model
n_keywords = 10  # Specify number of keywords to extract
ngram = 3  # Specify ngram of keywords

# Apply KeyBERT model extraction function along 'Text' axis of pandas dataframe
memo_keywords_df = memo_['Text'].apply(lambda x:
                                       kw_model.extract_keywords(x,
                                                                 keyphrase_ngram_range=(1, ngram),
                                                                 stop_words='english',
                                                                 highlight=False,
                                                                 top_n=n_keywords))
# Display results
for i, memo_keywords in enumerate(memo_keywords_df):
    print("-"*40 + "\nmemo_ #{}: top {} keywords (ngram range 1-{})".format(i, n_keywords, ngram))
    for keyword in memo_keywords:
        print(keyword)
```

### Output (ngram range 1 - 1)

```
----------------------------------------
memo_ #0: top 10 keywords (ngram range 1-1)
('camouflage', 0.5249)
('hiding', 0.489)
('stealthily', 0.4561)
('surroundings', 0.3757)
('spot', 0.3511)
('hidden', 0.3413)
('danger', 0.3008)
('confident', 0.2051)
('safe', 0.2015)
('angles', 0.1867)
----------------------------------------
memo_ #1: top 10 keywords (ngram range 1-1)
('river', 0.4445)
('green', 0.3592)
('pink', 0.3328)
('fluorescent', 0.2592)
('town', 0.1814)
('surprise', 0.1272)
('different', 0.0962)
('day', 0.074)
('official', 0.0717)
('called', 0.0641)
```

### Output (ngram range 1 - 3)

```
----------------------------------------
memo_ #0: top 10 keywords (ngram range 1-3)
('hiding spot', 0.6575)
('spot perfect camouflage', 0.6302)
('camouflage thought', 0.6168)
('perfect camouflage thought', 0.6161)
('camouflage thought picked', 0.568)
('perfect camouflage', 0.5675)
('descending hiding spot', 0.5408)
('camouflage', 0.5249)
('stealthily descending hiding', 0.5181)
('descending hiding', 0.4991)
----------------------------------------
memo_ #1: top 10 keywords (ngram range 1-3)
('river green river', 0.6171)
('called green river', 0.599)
('river green', 0.5771)
('river fluorescent pink', 0.55)
('green river sense', 0.5445)
('sense river green', 0.5426)
('day green river', 0.5246)
('town green river', 0.5243)
('official town green', 0.4933)
('green river fluorescent', 0.4859)
```